My WD hard drive isn't working after upgrading my system from Big Sur to Sonoma
I just upgraded my Mac from Big Sur to Sonoma. I have a hard drive - WD My Passport (1 TB) - the hard drive LED light is lit but the drive is not showing on my Mac.
I tried using a different laptop with same OS version (Sonoma) and it is also not mounting.
Please tell me whether I should downgrade my system all the way from Big Sur to Sonoma or is there any possible way to use that hard drive?
Please give a solution how to make that hard drive compatible or how to go back from Sonoma to Big Sur.

It would help if you told us how it was formatted, also does it show up in system information when it is plugged in? (Apple Menu > About This Mac > More Info... > System Report) It may be that the drive died and it coincidentally happened during the upgrade, as an upgrade of macOS could not, in any way, damage an external drive.

Sonoma has newly-made problems with external filesystems, maybe this is what is happening to you.  https://www.macintouch.com/post/39104/macos-14-sonoma-vs-exfat/
